# UIButton size appears as DEFAULT at runtime despite being resized in XIB

Tags: ipad, uibutton, size, universal

I have a iPhone app I am converting to Universal.  I properly set up the `MainWindow-iPad.xib` and tied its view controller to my view controller class and all the other links etc and at run time, under the iPad simulator the App WORKS Perfectly...

However, I have 2 buttons in the `XIB` for `iPad`, and while in the `XIB` they are both resized from the default size to the sizes I want, and appear properly, at runtime under `IPAD` they appear as though the are still the default size when added to the `XIB`.

All other things done to the buttons appear proper, images, text, backgrounds etc are all working perfectly fine, but for some reason on the `IPAD` and `IPAD Emulator` only they are ignoring the size the `XIB` says they should be.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I have double and triple checked all the settings for the buttons in the `XIB` editor to ensure there is nothing different between the `IPAD` and `IPHONE xib` files related to these `UIButtons`, but they still appear at runtime with the wrong size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, DOH! moment... had an explicit XIB load in the code... so it was always loading the default MainWindow.xib no matter what...